# JSX not spitting HTML as expected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, jsx

i have the code

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Categories extends Component {
renderCategory(category, categoryIndex) {
    return (
        <div>{category}</div>
    );
};

renderCategories() {
    return _.map(this.props.categories, (category, categoryIndex) => {
        console.dir(category);
        this.renderCategory(category, categoryIndex);
    });
}

render() {
    console.dir(this.props.categories);
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderCategories()}
        </div>
    );
}
}


export default Categories;
```

and i'm calling this component from another one like this:

```
<Categories categories={{'an-example': "another"}}/>
```

now i get no HTML response associated, but the console logs do appear:

```
Object
an-example: "another"__proto__: Object
bundle.js:46448 another
```

What am i missing? How do i get the divs to be printed in the DOM? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing `return` keyword. It should be `return this.renderCategory(category, categoryIndex);`

Comment: thanks @Prakashsharma ! i overlooked it, over and over... :)